# Signature-Pad: looping through each canvas to create a signature-pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, canvas

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.signature-pad').each(function () {
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad($(this), {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
            penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        })
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative; width:400px; height: 200px; -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none">
  <canvas id="signature-pad1" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200 style=" position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width:400px; height:200px;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative; width:400px; height: 200px; -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none">
  <canvas id="signature-pad2" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200 style=" position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width:400px; height:200px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

The idea is that my included js library from https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/tree/v1.5.3  will create a signature pad out of each canvas. The js should loop through each canvas with class="signature-pad".

Problem is that if I have just the one canvas with id="signature-pad" then it works as expected, but if I have multiple canvases with the same class but numbered ids then it doesn't recognize them. Can someone help me figure out why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.signature-pad').each(function () {
            var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById(this.id), {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
            })
        });
```

Signature_Pad was expecting an element and I thought $(this) would give that, but apparently not. So, I used document.getElementById(this.id) and it worked as expected.